# .wrap() in jQuery (Multiple)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html code

```
<div id="div1">
    <span>Title</span>
</div>
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="div2">
    <span>Title</span>
</div>
<table id="table2">
    <tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I need is, I want to wrap div1 and table1 together.
By using `$('#table1, #div1').wrap('<div></div>')` It can wrap only one by one.
Is there a way to wrap both together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `.wrapAll()`.

```
$('#table1, #div1').wrapAll('<div></div>');
```